# How to store the results in a database to see history results

Tags: c#, database

I am making a game where people listen to determine whether something is black or white. I want to store how many times they got it correct and how many times they got it wrong in a database so they can see the old results.

What kind of database (like Sqlite) should I use? How should I save this information and display it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BinarySerializtion, XMLSerialization,......

so first create a class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Result 
{
  Public int TimesRight {get;set;}
  Public int TimesWrong {get;set;}

}
```

now in your game:

```
 Result result = new Result();
 result.TimesRight = x; //value of times right
 result.TimesWrong = y; //value of times wrong
```

Now choose the way you want to save it, here are some references for Binary and XML serialization:

[Binary Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
[XML Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx)